# Check details present in MySQL server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am currently coding my first Android app using Android Studio. I have a login and register page. I am able to add users to the MySQL server but now I am trying to make sure the users don't occur twice. I have implemented a Boolean method in my register activity which checks this before the register operation is carried out. However, I am not sure how to receive the response via the PHP file so this method can work correctly

This is the method in my Register activity class:

```
private Boolean notUser(User user) {
    boolean exists = true;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://point_collector.netau.net/checkUser");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        //Identifies the objects to be passed for the PHP files
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("username", user.username)
                .appendQueryParameter("email", user.email);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
        //Records entry
        Log.d("query", query);
        //Opens an output stream to send the data to be verified
        // and then closes the all output streams and flushes the output writer
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        //saves the response code to ensure connection was succesful
        int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("code", Integer.toString(code));

        //Opens an input stream to retrieve verified data back from the server
        //Starts a String Builder to read the data off the input
        //Closes the BufferedReader once it has finished building the string
        InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        responseStreamReader.close();

        String response = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.d("response",response);

        if(response.contains("This user already exist")) {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username or email already exist, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exists = false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return exists;
}
```

and this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","xxxxxx");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

    $parentUExists = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM Parent");
    $childUExists = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM Child");

    $parentEExist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM Parent");
    $childEExist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM Child");

    if(($email == $parentEExist || $email == $childEExist) && ($username == $parentUExist || $username == $childUExist)) {
       echo "This user already exist";
       mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else {
       echo "Ok";
       mysqli_close($con);
   }
?>
```

If anybody could offer me some advice I would greatly appreciate it as I am quite stuck.

Thank you

Comment: We don't see your php file?

Comment: If you create a unique constraint for each field (username and email) MySQL will let you know with an error code [1022 (ER_DUP_KEY)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key) when the same value is already in the database.

Comment: Are you in control of the MySql table? If so, you could add an unique index on the table column that uniquely identifies a user (username or email address for example).

Comment: I see, but then the issue would be how I would handle that error in my java files

Comment: You can e.g. send a message as an JSON object. Something like `echo json_encode( array('status'=>'failed', 'reason'=>'username or email already in database') );`

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a go. Thanks for your help

Comment: If I have the attribute set to UNIQUE, will that just count for that particular table or will it cover the whole DB?

Comment: For the fields of the table that are encompassed by the unique index/constraint.

Comment: Found the error, left out the .php in the URL